# Laptop touchpad stops working randomly on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

My Acer laptop touchpad stops working after some time on Ubuntu 18.04. The keyboard and external USB mouse works fine. The touchpad starts working after a system restart.

I tried using recommended fix of installing 'xserver-xorg-input-synaptics' but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a hardware issue? My Acer's touchpad stopped working after a reboot of my laptop.

Comment: I doubt it's a hardware issue. I notice that the touchpad specifically stops working after I run a memory intensive program. (e.g. playing supertuxkart, or running a memory intenstive script on a jupyter notebook)

Comment: Could it be the heat of the laptop doing something on a half broken connection?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. For me, usually I could restore it by Suspend then log in again, which is less disruptive than a full restart, so I set the power button to Suspend so this would be easier.

As for cause and prevention, it will vary by device, but I just discovered that my touchpad is set up with a "feature" that disables the touchpad completely (leaving no trace in any settings that the device even exists) on a double-tap in a particular corner. My touchpad often disables when the fan changes speed while my finger is touching the touchpad, so I'm guessing that something about the fan motion makes the device think I double-tapped that corner. I'm looking in to how to disable that "feature".

I've seen other posts talking about static etc from the fan interfering with their touchpad - there might be something similar with yours.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Changing touchpad from advanced to basic (through BIOS), and installing i2c-tools helped fix my issue. Thread regarding the same [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223111/acer-aspire-touchpad-not-detected).

Comment: It would be nice if you add a screenshot of the BIOS settings that has to be changed