# Touchpad stopped working after removing external mouse on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, acer

I was using a mouse on my notebook and everything was fine. But after removing the mouse, the touchpad wasn't working anymore.

I installed Tweaks using:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

to check the status of the touchpad option, but it was already active, so I couldn't do anything.

My notebook is an Acer Aspire 5 A515-54G-53GP, but I don't think that the problem is hardware-related, since the notebook is just over 1 month old.

Comment: After unplugging the mouse, what works for me is closing the lid (going to sleep), and opening it again, and the touchpad seems to works again. Obviously this is anecdotal, and just a thought. I don't use GNOME, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: I did that, restarted etc. But nothing works, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Here is what I did to solve it:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all
```

If above commands return that all packages are installed correctly, then try following:
**This might make your Ubuntu installation useless if anything fails**

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-all -y && sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Comment: sorry for the delay, I had no hope that someone would respond. I will be without internet now, but in about 1 hour I can test.

Answer (score 0):

I think may be your mentioning this type of issue change touchpad mode to adavanced to basic it works for me. refer this thread.

[Laptop touchpad stops working randomly on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195868/laptop-touchpad-stops-working-randomly-on-ubuntu-18-04)